# Pandas read_csv with escapechar is not consistent for an column?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I tried to read a time series csv files (fig. 1), but I don't want the ":" in the first column name, so I used escapechar -- `data = pd.read_csv(dir_in + file, skiprows=1,sep=',',escapechar=':')`.  The ":" in Time column is escaped as well, but it's not consistent -- it seems read in as string at beginning but read in as number after a while (fig. 2)?

[image: Figure 1. The original file]
Figure 1. The original file

[image: Figure 2. The data after <code>data = pd.read_csv(dir_in + file, skiprows=1,sep=',',escapechar=':')</code>]

Figure 2. The data after `data = pd.read_csv(dir_in + file, skiprows=1,sep=',',escapechar=':')`

Comment: It's easier just read it as usual and rename the `hh:mm` column to `hhmm`.

Comment: Thanks, @QuangHoang, that works better, and I just need to change my first column name, ": Date" into "Date".

Comment: Thanks, @Merlin, I would like to keep the column names because there are a lot of files with different length of column names, and I'm going to loop them later.